# ¿Cómo puedo comparar cual palabra es mayor y cual es menor dentro de un arreglo de String en Java?

Tags: java

Agradeceria mucho si pudieran ayudarme un poco. Estoy aprendiendo en Java. En realidad quiero saber que palabra es mayor y cual menor dentro de un String. Solo eso, creo que estoy cerca, pero ustedes dicen.

```
    Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);
    int variable1 = 0, variable2 = 0;
    System.out.println("Ingresa algun tipo de frase");
    String texto = datos.nextLine();
    
    
    String [] palabras = texto.trim().split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
        
        if(palabras[i].length() > variable1){
            variable1 = palabras[i].length();
            
        }  
        if (palabras[i].length() < variable2) {
            variable2 = palabras[i].length();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("La palabra mayor es " + variable1);
    System.out.println("La palabra menor es " + variable2);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estabas casi ahí, pero veo un poco de confusión en los conceptos básicos. Quizás en esta etapa deberías plantear lo que quieres hacer en papel, en pseudocódigo.

Hay dos grandes fallos ahí, el primero es que en el bucle for usas la longitud total del texto introducido para determinar el número de iteraciones, cuando lo que queremos es recorrer el array de palabras, es decir queremos recorrer cada una de las palabras para saber cuál es la más larga y cuál la más corta.

El otro fallo es que en variable1 y variable2 estás almacenando las longitudes, no la palabra más larga y la más corta, respectivamente. Además, ¿porqué llamarlas variable1 y variable2, que no nos dicen nada sobre su naturaleza, sobre lo que representan? ¿No es mejor algo como "larga" y "corta" ó "max" y "min"?

Dicho todo esto, si corregimos esos fallos, tu código quedaría así

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPalabras {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingresa algún tipo de frase");

    String texto = datos.nextLine();

    String[] palabras = texto.trim().split(" ");

    String max = palabras[0];
    String min = palabras[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < palabras.length; i++) {

        if (palabras[i].length() > max.length()) {
            max = palabras[i];
        }

        if (palabras[i].length() < min.length()) {
            min = palabras[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("La palabra más larga es '" + max + "' con una longitud de " + max.length() + " caracteres");
    System.out.println("La palabra más corta es '" + min + "' con una longitud de " + min.length() + " caracteres");
}
}
```

Si te fijas, he inicializado las variables max y min con la primera palabra, esa va a ser siempre la más larga y la más corta si el texto introducido tiene una sola palabra. Luego el bucle recorre el resto de palabras, desde la segunda - índice 1 - hasta la longitud del array menos 1, debido a que los índices de los arrays empiezan en cero en lugar de en 1.

Por último, informarte también que si quieres recorrer un array entero usando un bucle for, java te ofrece la posibilidad de hacer esto

```
    for (String palabraActual : palabras) {

        if (palabraActual.length() > max.length()) {
            max = palabraActual;
        }

        if (palabraActual.length() < min.length()) {
            max = palabraActual;
        }
    }
```

[image: Prueba de ejecución]

Comment: En realidad no sabes cuanto te agradezco por tu respuesta, estoy en 2do semestre de universidad y le estoy encontrando el gusto. Antes solo hice una página en html pero que va, comencé mi primer hello World en Java. Y cada día me causa fascinación tantas cosas relacionadas a mi carrera que soy como un niño en una gigantesca jugetería. Un Saludo desde Morelos.

Comment: @RodolfoGaHndz Encantado de ayudarte. Aquí estaremos para echarte una mano. Siempre que te hayas trabajado el tema previamente. Suerte con esos estudios. Un saludo desde Málaga, España!

Comment: @RodolfoGaHndz Marca mi respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió